# Inserting array of data in database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, insert

I have two arrays of values:

First array contain user id's:

```
Array ([0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3 [3]=>4 [4]=>5 [5]=>6)
```

Second array contain attendance status:

```
Array([0]=>Present [1]=>Absent [2]=>Absent [3]=>Present [4]=>Absent [5]=>Present)
```

I want to insert these values in the database in separate rows like this:

```
U_id                        Status

 1                          Present
 2                          Absent
 3                          Absent
 4                          Present
 5                          Absent
 6                          Present
```

Currently, I am using this code to insert values in database.

My Controller Code:

```
public function usr_att(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $status= $_POST['stat'];
        $id = implode("," , $uid );
        $status = implode("," , $status );
        $data = array (
          'u_id' => $id,
          'status' => $status
        );
        $this->db->insert('attendence' , $data);
        redirect("usr/usr_list", "refresh");
    }
}
```

But this code inserts data like this:

```
U_id                Status

 1                  Present,Absent,Absent,Present,Absent,Present
```

How can I insert these values in separate rows using CodeIgniter?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do like this

```
public function usr_att()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $status = $_POST['stat'];

        foreach ($uid as $key => $item) 
        {
            $data = array (
                'u_id' => $item,
                'status' => $status[$key]
            );
            $this->db->insert('attendence' , $data);
        }
        redirect("usr/usr_list", "refresh");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help its working according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For your intended purpose, once you have the values for $uid and $stat in an array, then you could do this:

```
<?php

// You have your u_id values in an array
$uid = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');

// You have your status values in an array
$stat = array('Present', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Present', 'Absent', 'Present');

// As long as the number of u_id values and status values are the same
if( count($uid) == count($stat) )
{
    // Use the count of uid values and loop through
    for( $x = 0; $x <= count($uid) -1; $x++ )
    {
        // Entering each on in the database
        $this->db->insert('attendence', array(
            'u_id'   => $uid[$x],
            'status' => $stat[$x]
        ));
    }
}
```